# Add factor for each loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a the following table

| Default | Survival | LoanID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.9 | 0.1 | 1 |
| 0.85 | 0.15 | 2 |
| 0.92 | 0.08 | 3 |
| 0.86 | 0.14 | 4 |
| 0.7 | 0.3 | 5 |
| 0.82 | 0.18 | 6 |

as an example and the following code

```
TD <- character() 
TD
for(i in 1:n) {

PD_2 <- prod(credit$Survival[1:n])*credit$Default[i]/credit$survival[i]*credit$Default[i+1]/credit$Survival[i+1]

TD <- c(TD, PD_2)

}

credit$TD <- as.numeric(TD)
```

I want to add a new factor for each loop, so first [1], [2], [3] and so on

```
*credit$Default[i+1:n]/credit$Survival[i+1:n]
```

for every iteration but am not sure how. So, in the end it should be

```
...credit$Default[i+1]/credit$Survival[i+1]*credit$Default[i+2]/credit$Survival[i+2]*credit$Default[i+3]/credit$Survival[i+3]*...*credit$Default[i+n-1]/credit$Survival[i+n-1]
```

Help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you can explain what you're trying to do, and what would be your desired output with the data given. Given that R vectorizes there's likely no need for a for loop.

Comment: I want to have the probability of different scenarios. Like, how likely is it that Loan 1 defaults while the rest doesn't. How likely is it, that Loan 2, 3, 4 default, while the rest doesn't and so on. So every possible possibility of every scenario

Comment: Can you please post an expected output data frame? By all possibilities, do you mean all combinations of default and not for each of them (hundreds of combos), or just one defaults and the rest to not (much fewer combos)?

Comment: The idea is for instance. What if Loan 1 survives, but 2:6 doesn't. What if 2 survives but 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, doesn't. What if 1, 2 survive, while 3, 4, 5, 6 doesn't and so on. So all combinations of defaults vs. survival

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are computing your probabilities correctly. The probability of Default on the first loan AND Survival on the second loan is .9 * .15 = .135. The probabilities for all combinations of 6 loans would be as follows:

```
credit <- structure(list(Default = c(0.9, 0.85, 0.92, 0.86, 0.7, 0.82), 
    Survival = c(0.1, 0.15, 0.08, 0.14, 0.3, 0.18), LoanID = 1:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))   
# Use dput() to provide data frame

perms <- t(expand.grid(1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2))  
# Compute all permutations of 6 loans - There are 64. Many more if you want subsets of loans. 
# Each column indicates if the loan is Default (1) or Survive (2) for each row.

results <- sapply(1:64, function(i) prod(credit[cbind(1:6, perms[, i])]))
head(result)
# [1] 0.347423832 0.038602648 0.061310088 0.006812232 0.030210768 0.003356752
```

The first probability is .3474 that all 6 loans are Default and .0386 that the first loan is Survival and the rest are Default. The 6th probability is for Survival, Default, Survival, Default, Default, Default, and so on for all 64 permutations.